# Server is not receiving all the files sent from client in Python

Tags: python

I have written client and server code in Python. In the code, the client is getting a path as an input from the user. The path can be of a folder or a file. After that, the client traverses that folder/directory and sends all the files inside it and inside its sub folders to the server, but the problem is that the server is receiving only one file although client is sending all the files to the server.

What is the problem?

**Client Code:**

```
from socket import *
import fnmatch
import os


serverIP = '10.99.26.144'
serverPort = 12000
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((serverIP, serverPort))
path = input('Input Path:')


if os.path.exists(path):
    clientSocket.send(bytes(path, 'UTF-8'))


    if os.path.isfile(path):
        file = open(path, "rb")
        data = file.read(1024)
        while (data):
            clientSocket.send(data)
            data = file.read(1024)
        file.close()

    else:
        for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
            for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.*'):
                print( os.path.join(root, filename).encode('utf-8') )
                clientSocket.send(os.path.join(root, filename).encode('utf-8'))
                file = open(root+"\\"+filename, "rb")
                data = file.read(1024)
                while (data):
                    clientSocket.send(data)
                    data = file.read(1024)
                file.close()
        clientSocket.send("".encode('utf-8'))

else:
    print("Path is invalid!")

clientSocket.close()
print("connection closed")
```

**Server Code:**

```
from socket import *
import os


serverPort = 12000
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print('The server is ready to receive')
connectionSocket, address = serverSocket.accept()
path = connectionSocket.recv(1024)


if os.path.isfile(path):
    file = open(os.path.basename(path), 'wb') #Open in binary
    data = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
    while (data):
        file.write(data)
        data = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
    file.close()

else:
    while True:
        path = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        print(path)
        if path.decode('utf-8')=="":
            break
        fileName = os.path.basename(path).decode('utf-8')
        drive, tail = os.path.splitdrive( os.path.dirname(path))
        directory = os.getcwd()+tail.decode('utf-8')
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)

        file = open( directory + "\\" + fileName, 'wb') #Open in binary
        data = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        while (data):
            file.write(data)
            data = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        file.close()

connectionSocket.close()
print("connection closed")
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem here is you were creating the file only once (the first file). and then writing all the received content (file paths also) to the same file.

```
else:  
    while True:
        path = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        print(path)
        if path.decode('utf-8')=="":
            break
        fileName = os.path.basename(path).decode('utf-8')
        drive, tail = os.path.splitdrive( os.path.dirname(path) )
        directory = os.getcwd()+tail.decode('utf-8')
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            **os.makedirs(directory)**
```

In the below while loop, you were just writing the data to the file created above

```
    while (data):
        file.write(data)
        data = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
    file.close()
```

You'd need to add create new file for every read in the above while loop.

Comment: I am opening the new file everytime file = open( directory +"\\"+ fileName, 'wb' ) at line:36

Comment: Yes you did, but as your logic says it only creates file in the first iteration, remaining all the iterations just appends data to it.

Comment: @RaeesKhan Adding more to this your logic is purely asynchronous. Client never waits for Server and your server never wait for your client. you'd need to put some protocols to handle this operation by file by file or multiple files by threading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this client and server to transfer files in synchronous mode. transfer happens file by file, when ever client sends data to server it expects some response from the server, in this way I've created some protocol to transfer files. you might need to modify some statements as you required.

I've modified only for multiple files case, keep that in mind.

**Client:**

```
from socket import *
import fnmatch
import os


serverIP = '127.0.0.1'
serverPort = 12000
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((serverIP,serverPort))
path = raw_input('Input Path:')


if os.path.exists(path):
    clientSocket.send(bytes(path))
    path_resp = clientSocket.recv(1024)


    if os.path.isfile(path):
        file = open(path, "rb")
        data = file.read(1024)
        while (data):
            clientSocket.send(data)
            data = file.read(1024)
        file.close()


    else:
        file_list = []
        for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
            for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.*'):
                file_list.append(os.path.join(root, filename).encode('utf-8'))
        print file_list
        file_list = iter(file_list)
        while True:
            file_transfer_done = False
            try:
                file_name = file_list.next()
            except StopIteration, e:
                str(e)
                break

            print('Sent file name to server %s' % file_name)
            clientSocket.send(file_name)
            file_resp = clientSocket.recv(1024)
            print('Received server response : %s' % file_resp)
            file = open(file_name, "rb")
            data = file.read(1024)
            while True:
                if data:
                    clientSocket.send(data)
                    print('Sent data to server')
                    data_resp = clientSocket.recv(1024)
                    print('Received server responce : %s' % data_resp)
                data = file.read(1024)
                if not data:
                    clientSocket.send('file_closed')
                    close_resp = clientSocket.recv(1024)
                    break
            file.close()
        clientSocket.send("close".encode('utf-8'))


else:
    print("Path is invalid!")

clientSocket.close()
print("connection closed")
```

**Server:**

```
from socket import *
import os


serverPort = 12000
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print('The server is ready to receive')
connectionSocket, address = serverSocket.accept()
path = connectionSocket.recv(1024)

connectionSocket.send('path_received')

if os.path.isfile(path):
    file = open(os.path.basename(path), 'wb' )
    data = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
    while (data):
        file.write(data)
        data = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
    file.close()


else:
    while True:
        path = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        print('Received file from client: %s' % path)
        connectionSocket.send('file_path_received')
        print('Sent responce to client : %s' % ('file_path_received'))

        if path.decode('utf-8')=="":
            break
        fileName = os.path.basename(path)
        print('File name received : %s' % fileName)
        drive, tail = os.path.splitdrive( os.path.dirname(path) )
        directory = os.getcwd()+tail
        print directory
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)

        file = open( directory +"/"+ fileName, 'wb' )
        print('New file created : %s' % fileName)
        data = connectionSocket.recv(1024)

        while True:
            file.write(data)
            print('File write done')
            connectionSocket.send('Processed')
            data = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
            if 'file_closed' in data:
                connectionSocket.send('file_done')
                break
        file.close()


connectionSocket.close()
print("connection closed")
```

Note: This is a sample code I've tried, you can make this better.